# Python code for Reading Text Label Associated wit Toggle switch in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to turn on/off a toggle switch using the selenium code. The issue is that I would like to access the toggle switch by its "text label" rather than its ID or Name. Here is the HTML for the switch

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ot-group-id-C0002" class="switch-checkbox category-switch-handler" id="ot-group-id-C0002" aria-checked="true" aria-controls="ot-desc-id-C0002" aria-labelledby="ot-header-id-C0002" data-optanongroupid="C0002" checked="true" tabindex="0">
<label class="switch-label" for="ot-group-id-C0002">
    <span class="switch-inner"></span> 
    <span class="switch-nob"></span> 
    <span class="label-text">Performance Cookies</span>
</label>
```

I would like to access the toggle switch via the text "Performance Cookies" rather than its ID or Name.

Comment: Your code trials please

Answer (score 1):

you can read my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61641425/13329248) for details to use xpath in selenium.

additional info i didn't mention there but would help you:

to search by text we use:

```
//*[text()='Performance Cookies']
```

to get its parent(label) we use:

```
ancestor::label
```

to get the preceding(the tag/element before) which is an input we use

```
preceding::input
```

now combine all that and we get:

```
//*[text()='Performance Cookies']/ancestor::label/preceding::input[@type='checkbox']
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help, but the code seems to be doing something strange .. Its finding the same element no matter what I put as text() = ..... E.g.
for the code: 

MyVar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Performance Cookies']/ancestor::label/preceding::input[@type='checkbox']")

and 

MyVar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Functional Cookies']/ancestor::label/preceding::input[@type='checkbox']")

It seems to be selecting the same element. i.e. the functional cookies toggle switch. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: its hard for me to tell why it went wrong without looking at the full html code, i recommend you to use google chrome, open the website, inspect elements, ctrl + f or cmd + f, type in the xpath, there you can do trial and error why it works/doesn't work. it will show which element the xpath points to by selecting it (yellow) like in the picture above.

Comment: Well... It might be just me :) This is the fourth query I have posted on this forum.. and none of them seems to close and gives me the final answer :) .. 
Anyways... thanks alot for your help! appreciate it. The problem still stands .. So please let me know if you have a light bulb moment re this in future..

Comment: @HardBoiledPotato That was a canonical answer with a useful details. But seems OP doesn't have a concrete usecase.