# How Can I automate Selenium to click a web element based on another web elements value?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

im automating some data entry tasks using selenium and Python. I basically want to automate clicking a students name(hyperlink) based on there student status.

So I want to click the circled link based on the value "ST" or "Student"

[image: So I want to click the circled link based on the value "ST" or "Student"]

Answer (score 0):

you can read my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61641425/13329248) for details to use xpath in selenium.

additional info i didn't mention there but would help you: to search the text student, the xpath would be,

```
//*[text()='Student']
```

and to search for value = ST,

```
//*[@value='ST']
```

Comment: Ok so if im understanding correctly chaining these two together should point to a unique element? if have it written as such in my program:
`name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()='Student'][@value='ST']').click()`
Also this gives me a syntax error. Please forgive Noob-ness this is day to figuring out selenium on the fly.